# Launch a Mac application from a JavaScript for Automation (JXA) script

Tags: javascript, macos, automator, javascript-automation

The AppleScript way to launch a Mac application is:

```
tell application "iTunes"
  activate
end tell
```

What's the equivalent in [JavaScript for Automation (JXA)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1)?

Comment: Can you please add the tag 'jxa' to this question?

Answer (score 4):

Launching an application via Mac's JavaScript for Automation is done like this:

```js
var itunes = Application('iTunes');
itunes.activate();
```

The `Application` call looks inside the `/Applications` directory. Any app there can be called by name.

The `.activate()` call starts the app and makes it the front window. If it's already running, the application is simply moved to the front window.

It appears the UI switch can take a little time. Use something like:

```js
delay(0.3);
```

to create a brief pause (three tenths of a second in this case) to let the UI catch up before continuing to send scripted commands to the app.